# Count duration of events and group in 24 hours intervals SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, report, intervals

I have table with data of events contains two dates: 
1) Event Start Date (eg. 2017-03-01 05:30:00) 
2) Event End Date  (eg. 2017-03-01 06:10:00)

I need create report with structure, where data are sum all events in given year-day and hour grouped in 24h time interval, like that:

Two rows:

```
Id      | Start date       | End date 
Event 1 | 2017-03-01 07:45 | 2017-03-01 08:15  
Event 2 | 2017-03-01 08:25 | 2017-03-01 08:40
```

And Query result:

```
Year-Month-Day | Hours | (Activity time in seconds or minutes - here minutes) 
2017-03-01     |    00 | 0 
2017-03-01     |    01 | 0 
2017-03-01     |    02 | 0
2017-03-01     |    03 | 0 
2017-03-01     |    04 | 0 
2017-03-01     |    05 | 0
2017-03-01     |    06 | 0 
2017-03-01     |    07 | 15
2017-03-01     |    08 | 30 
2017-03-01     |    09 | 00 
...
```

Is elegant way to do this in Oracle SQL? I wrote some psudocode in first moment, (where I count diff between start and end time, check how many hours were affected, and assign to right interval) , but maybe exist more native and better performance solution - like aggregate functions or etc?

Thanks for help.

Comment: did you try the search function here? there are plenty of answers about this topic

Comment: Sure, but all founded answers are focused on counting events in interval, not count event duration in 24h interval table in pure SQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Why 55 minutes? 
07-08 => 15 minutes (07:45 - 08:00 [E1])  
08-09 => 30 minutes (08:00 - 08:15 [E1] + 08:25: - 08:40 [E2])

Comment: @wukkie You're right, I misread your data, sorry.

Comment: As a hint, I think you're going to need a calendar table here.  Basically a dummy table, each record would be one date and one hour range.  You could then `LEFT JOIN` the calendar table to your data, with a little magic, and end up with the counts you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thats pretty much what I did in my answer below

Comment: @ArijitKanrar Tough question, thanks for answering it +1

Answer (score 2):

Here is a query that does what you need.
However note that this will only work for events that finish in 1 million minutes i.e. about 2 years.

```
WITH event
     AS (SELECT 'Event 1' AS id,
                '2017-03-01 07:45' AS start_date,
                '2017-03-01 08:15' AS end_date
         FROM   DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Event 2' AS id,
                '2017-03-01 08:25' AS start_date,
                '2017-03-01 08:40' AS end_date
         FROM   DUAL),
     add_mins
     AS (SELECT LEVEL
                - 1
                   AS add_min
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000000),
     hrs_in_day
     AS (SELECT LEVEL
                - 1
                   AS hr
         FROM   DUAL
         CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 24),
     all_days_hrs
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (SELECT TO_CHAR (
                           (first_start_day
                            + LEVEL
                            - 1),
                           'YYYY-MM-DD'
                        )
                           AS curr_day
                 FROM   (SELECT MIN (curr_day) AS first_start_day,
                                MAX (curr_day) AS last_end_day
                         FROM   (SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP (start_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
                                           AS curr_day
                                 FROM   event
                                 UNION
                                 SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP (end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
                                           AS curr_day
                                 FROM   event))
                 CONNECT BY (first_start_day
                             + LEVEL
                             - 1) < last_end_day),
                hrs_in_day)
SELECT hl.curr_day AS year_month_day,
       LPAD (hl.hr, 2, '0') AS hours,
       COUNT (h.curr_hr) AS activity_duration_in_min
FROM   all_days_hrs hl
       LEFT JOIN
       (SELECT id,
               start_time,
               end_time,
               curr_time,
               TO_CHAR (curr_time, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS year_month_day,
               EXTRACT (HOUR FROM curr_time) AS curr_hr
        FROM   (SELECT id,
                       start_time,
                       end_time,
                       b.add_min,
                       start_time
                       + NUMTODSINTERVAL (b.add_min, 'minute')
                          AS curr_time
                FROM   (SELECT id,
                               start_time,
                               end_time,
                               EXTRACT (DAY FROM dur_interval) * 1440
                               + EXTRACT (HOUR FROM dur_interval) * 60
                               + EXTRACT (MINUTE FROM dur_interval)
                                  AS duration_in_min
                        FROM   (SELECT id,
                                       start_time,
                                       end_time,
                                       (end_time
                                        - start_time)
                                          AS dur_interval
                                FROM   (SELECT id,
                                               TO_TIMESTAMP (
                                                  start_date,
                                                  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'
                                               )
                                                  AS start_time,
                                               TO_TIMESTAMP (
                                                  end_date,
                                                  'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'
                                               )
                                                  AS end_time
                                        FROM   event))) a,
                       add_mins b
                WHERE  b.add_min < a.duration_in_min)) h
          ON (hl.curr_day = h.year_month_day
              AND hl.hr = h.curr_hr)
GROUP BY hl.curr_day,
         hl.hr
ORDER BY year_month_day NULLS FIRST,
         hl.hr;
```

It is a bit slow though. I haven't spent any time thinking about performance.
But it works. Here is the output.

```
Year-Month-day  | Hours | Activity_Duration_in_min
    2017-03-01  | 00    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 01    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 02    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 03    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 04    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 05    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 06    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 07    | 15
    2017-03-01  | 08    | 30
    2017-03-01  | 09    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 10    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 11    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 12    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 13    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 14    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 15    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 16    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 17    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 18    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 19    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 20    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 21    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 22    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 23    | 0
```

And if we change the end date of 'Event 2' to 2017-03-02 (i.e. the event lasted one day and 15 min and 40 min in the 8th hour) we can see that the output changes to reflect the 48 hour duration.

```
Year-Month-day  | Hours | Activity_Duration_in_min
    2017-03-01  | 00    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 01    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 02    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 03    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 04    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 05    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 06    | 0
    2017-03-01  | 07    | 15
    2017-03-01  | 08    | 50
    2017-03-01  | 09    | 60
    2017-03-01  | 10    | 60
    2017-03-01  | 11    | 60
    2017-03-01  | 12    | 60
    2017-03-01  | 13    | 60
    2017-03-01  | 14    | 60
    2017-03-01  | 15    | 60
    2017-03-01  | 16    | 60
    2017-03-01  | 17    | 60
    2017-03-01  | 18    | 60
    2017-03-01  | 19    | 60
    2017-03-01  | 20    | 60
    2017-03-01  | 21    | 60
    2017-03-01  | 22    | 60
    2017-03-01  | 23    | 60
    2017-03-02  | 00    | 60
    2017-03-02  | 01    | 60
    2017-03-02  | 02    | 60
    2017-03-02  | 03    | 60
    2017-03-02  | 04    | 60
    2017-03-02  | 05    | 60
    2017-03-02  | 06    | 60
    2017-03-02  | 07    | 60
    2017-03-02  | 08    | 40
    2017-03-02  | 09    | 0
    2017-03-02  | 10    | 0
    2017-03-02  | 11    | 0
    2017-03-02  | 12    | 0
    2017-03-02  | 13    | 0
    2017-03-02  | 14    | 0
    2017-03-02  | 15    | 0
    2017-03-02  | 16    | 0
    2017-03-02  | 17    | 0
    2017-03-02  | 18    | 0
    2017-03-02  | 19    | 0
    2017-03-02  | 20    | 0
    2017-03-02  | 21    | 0
    2017-03-02  | 22    | 0
    2017-03-02  | 23    | 0
```

Comment: I was testing for one more possibility where one event last for more than two days here it will not show days which are in between. that is if we change the end date of 'Event 2' to 2017-03-03 then entries for day 2017-03-02 will not be present in output.